# CGContext does not update immediately

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, cgcontext

The Problem: I have a small game where u can scratch a image above another image. The upper image becomes invisible where you are scratching. The whole thing is placed into a SpriteKit view. The problem is, that on weaker devices (iPhone4) the scratching image is only updated when the user stops scratching.

I assume that the image is only updated when the user does not scratch until the image is completely rendered and displayed.

Can someone suggest a better way to see the scratching immediately. I am aware that the scratching consumes a lot of performance but I dont mind if it lags a little.

Here the code:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

[_scratchImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), _lastPoint.x, _lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 25.0f );
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

CGContextSetBlendMode (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

_scratchImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

_lastPoint = currentPoint;

SKTexture* scratchTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:_scratchImage];

_scratchSprite.texture = scratchTexture;


}
```

**UPDATE**

I ended up recording the points as suggested in the correct answer. But other than updating the image in a CADisplayLink callback I updated the screen in a

```
-(void)update(float currentTime)
```

callback from SpriteKit (Which is kind of the same for SpriteKit use cases)

My code in the update method looks like the following:

```
-(void)displayUpdated
 {


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

[_scratchImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

CGMutablePathRef linePath = nil;
linePath = CGPathCreateMutable();


CGPathMoveToPoint(linePath, NULL, _lastPoint.x, _lastPoint.y);


for (NSValue* val in _recordedPoints) {

    CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue];

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, NULL, p.x, p.y);

    NSLog(@"%f, %f", p.x, p.y);

    _lastPoint = p;

}
//flush array
[_recordedPoints removeAllObjects];


CGContextAddPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), linePath);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 25.0f );
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

CGContextSetBlendMode (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

_scratchImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

CGPathRelease(linePath);

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

SKTexture* scratchTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:_scratchImage];



_scratchSprite.texture = scratchTexture;

 }
```

A more performant code would also hold a reference to the context but I could not manage to get that working. If someone can suggest a solution I would be happy. Nevertheless my Framerate on a iPhone 4 went up to 25-30 fps from about 5 fps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following:

1. Measure in Instruments.app [Time Profiler](https://www.google.se/search?q=time+profiling+in+instrumetns).
2. Speed up drawing by creating a [CGBitmapContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/) as an instance variable. Then you can skip the `[_scratchImage drawInRect:...]` in each step.
3. Separate the drawing and the event handling. Right now, you will always create a new `UIImage` for each touch event. It could be better to coalesce the stroked lines so the creation of a `UIImage` does not happen as often. E.g. put the line segments in a queue and draw in a callback from [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer I will try this right away. I cant give u a upvote because I dont have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about SpriteKit, In UIView, you should put your drawing code in drawRect method. Is it the same as SpriteKit ?